# PHP I need to split a comma separated string into an array, BUT when the comma appear between digits ignore it

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string sent to php and I need to turn it into a array. In most cases there is no problem becuase the string is delimited by commas in the correct plac3es. BUT occasionally there is a comma between two digits that I need to ignore. I have tried preg_split with look behind and look forward but I always lose one of the final or beginning letters of a string.

I have been struggling with this for days. I can't use explode, or the array contains sub-strings bropken at the 1,2 commas.

For example:

```
bears, tigers, lions, sword-1,2-fish, penguins
```

I need the php to ignore the comma in sword-1,2-fish and return:

```
[0] ==> bears
[1] ==> tigers
[2] ==> lions
[3] ==> sword-1,2-fish
[4] ==> penguins
```

Anyone help, please?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not as simple as exploding on comma + space?

Comment: `print_r(preg_split('~(?=\D)\s*,\s*(?=\D)~', $str));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your contributions - I finally sorted it out using as suggested above, a lookaround.

```
$pattern = "/(?<=\D),(?=\D)/";                  // the expression only accepts commas that are NOT preceded by or followed by a digit (\D is NOT a digit)
$arr = preg_split($pattern, $data8);


$wrongArray="";
foreach ($arr as $wrong){
$wrongArray.="<li style='font-family:Verdana;font-size:12px;color:maroon'>".$wrong."</li>";
}
```

I'm going to study the other suggestions too, to see why they work.
Thanks very much all.

Comment: As well as your answer left you string with spaces.So basically you are not getting desired output:- https://3v4l.org/0vZLd

Comment: You appear to be correct, but in my working file I'm not actually getting any spaces. Here is an example output as mailed back to me:
    1. Enthalpy changes - combustion enthalpies
    2. Hess law - calculation of reaction enthalpy change
    4. Enthalpy changes - endothermic reactions
    5. Energy level diagrams - reaction profiles.

As you see, they are answers to questions. I don't know why my solution works ...

Comment: Actually, I am parsing a string that is made (in a different file) from the members of an array, so there are no actual spaces in the array. 'bears,tigers,lions,sword-1,2-fish,penguins'. I didn't make this clear in the original question because I didn't think that it was relevant. All of the answers above are clearly correct if there are spaces. I should've been more specific.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfect case to use [negative lookbehind and negative lookahead](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php):

```php
$string = 'bears, tigers, lions, sword-1,2-fish, penguins';
$result = preg_split('#(?<!\d)\s*,\s*(?!\d)#', $string);
```

Comment: I think I figured it out, the original regex, `'#(?!\d),(?!\d)#'` works because it has 2 negative lookbehinds, it is the same as `'#,(?!\d)#'`, if it finds a `,` followed by a number matches. But it won't match if the `,` only has a number in front of it, but say, a space behind. The updated version `'#(?<!\d),(?!\d)#'` matches the OP's question, it won't match if there is a number behind *or* in front of the `,`.

Comment: It makes sense.

Comment: Your answer left you string with spaces.So basically you are not getting desired output:-https://3v4l.org/gkFKs

Comment: Good catch. Edited to handle whitespace.